# Core Data family members grouped by surname

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

This is my first attempt on Core Data so I would like your guidance.

My example project is quite simple, I would like to create an iOS app that displays a list of people. What I am looking for is to group all members of the same family together. Some people in the list do not belong to a "family". So, `UITableView` is going to be a mixture of groups and rows.

Here is my `Model` so far.
[image]

and here I am adding data in the context

```
    Family *newFamily = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@“Family” inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [newFamily setSurname:[dict objectForKey:@“surname”]];

    NSMutableSet *members = [newTeam mutableSetValueForKey:@"members"];

    for (NSDictionary *member in [dict objectForKey:@"members"]) {
        Member *newMember = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Member" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        [newMember setFirstName:[member objectForKey:@"firstName"]];
        [newMember setAge:[member objectForKey:@“age”]];

        [members addObject:newMember];
    }

//Save context ...
```

In `UITableViewController` I am able to read and display just families'/groups' name. I am confused on how do you display all the objects of a section.

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Family" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"surname" ascending:NO];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"surname" cacheName:@"Master"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO DO HERE ...
//    return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][section];
    return [sectionInfo name];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to amend your model to include the inverse relationship, from `Member` to `Family`, which presumably is "to-one".  Name that relationship "family".  (This inverse relationship is needed in this case, see below, but you should almost always include inverses for all relationships, regardless of whether you think you need them.)

Next, amend your FRC configuration as follows: the underlying entity should be `Member`, since each row of your tableView will represent a `Member` object.  The `sectionNameKeyPath` should be "family.surname" so the FRC will automatically put the `Member` objects into sections based on the `surname` attribute of the related `Family` object.  It is important that the sort order for the FRC matches up with the sections (ie all `Member` objects in the same section must be sorted together), so amend the sort descriptors to use `family.surname` (you could then sort by `firstName` if desired):

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Member" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *surnameSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"family.surname" ascending:NO];
    NSSortDescriptor *firstNameSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:NO];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[surnameSortDescriptor, firstNameSortDescriptor]];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"family.surname" cacheName:@"Master"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Finally, there is boilerplate code for linking an FRC to a tableView (see the Apple Docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/)).  The piece you are missing is:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if ([[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count] > 0) {
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
        return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    } else
        return 0;
}
```

Your `configureCell` method will likewise need to determine the correct `Member` object to display using

```
Member *currentMember = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Note that the FRC will log a warning message if there are `Member` objects that are not in a `Family`, since the `sectionName` will be nil.  But it will group these all together - you might want to amend the `titleForHeaderInSection` to use a different name for that section.

Also, note that the FRC's sections are determined by inspecting the `family.surname` for each `Member` object.  If there are `Family` objects that have no `members`, those `Family` objects will not appear in the table view (i.e. no empty sections).